# “How to fix trigger in oracle pl/sql?

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

Problem:
Need a TRIGGER for the Table A which does the following:
 Each time an INSERT is made into Table A on column TRT_PROCEDURE value, add 1 
 to the column 'TRT_INS_COUNT' in the table B. If the TRT_PROCEDURE value does 
 not exist in the table B, add a row to the table B for the procedure setting 
 TRT_INS_COUNT to 1.

Each time a DELETE is made on Table A, add 1 to the column TRT_DEL_COUNT in 
 table B for that Procedure value if it exists in the table B. If it does not 
 exist in the table B, add a row to the table B for the procedure and set 
 TRT_DEL_COUNT to 1.

Each time an UPDATE occurs for Column TRT_PROCEDURE in TABLE A, add 1 to the 
 column TRT_UPD_COUNT in table B. If it is not in the table B, add a row to 
 the table B for the procedure value and set TRT_UPD_COUNT to 1. If the Column 
 TRT_PROCEDURE value in TABLE A is changed, add 1 to the TRT_UPD_COUNT for the 
 old procedure value.

Test by doing several INSERTs, DELETEs, and UPDATEs and then display the table B.

Updates: whenever an value of trt_procedure is inserted into table B, the second same trt_procedure (e.g '88-20') cannot be correctly counted into its designated count field. Not sure where went wrong.

```
TABLE A
Name    Null     Type
TRT_ID  NOT NULL NUMBER(3)
PAT_NBR          NUMBER(4)
PHYS_ID          NUMBER(3)
TRT_PROCEDURE    VARCHAR2(5)
TRT_DATE         DATE


TABLE B
Name          Null     Type
TRT_PROCEDURE NOT NULL VARCHAR2(5)
TRT_INS_COUNT          NUMBER(3)
TRT_DEL_COUNT          NUMBER(3)
TRT_UPD_COUNT          NUMBER(3)

 TEST SAMPLES
  INSERT INTO A VALUES (11, 8031,101,'88-20',sysdate );
  INSERT INTO A VALUES (12, 5872,101,'60-00',sysdate );
  UPDATE A SET trt_procedure = '88-20' WHERE trt_id=6;
   /*row trt_id =6 cloumn trt_procedure old value '54-60'
    new value '88-20', which means Table B row '88-20' and
    row '54-60 both trt_upd_count should add 1*/

  DELETE FROM A WHERE trt_id=1; 
  /*row trt_id =1 cloumn trt_procedure value also '88-20', which means
    that Table B row '88-20' trt_del_count should also add 1*/

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trt_stats_trg
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE OF TRT_procedure ON A FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF INSERTING THEN
    UPDATE B SET trt_ins_count = trt_ins_count+1
    WHERE B.trt_procedure = :new.trt_procedure;
    IF SQL%NOTFOUND THEN
    INSERT INTO B (trt_procedure, trt_ins_count)
    VALUES (:new.trt_procedure, 1);
    END IF;

 ELSIF UPDATING THEN
   UPDATE B SET trt_upd_count = trt_upd_count+1
   WHERE B.trt_procedure = :old.trt_procedure;
   IF SQL%NOTFOUND THEN
   INSERT INTO B (trt_procedure, trt_upd_count)
   VALUES (:old.trt_procedure, 1);
   END IF;
   UPDATE B SET trt_upd_count = trt_upd_count+1
   WHERE B.trt_procedure = :new.trt_procedure;
   IF SQL%NOTFOUND THEN
   INSERT INTO B (trt_procedure, trt_upd_count)
   VALUES (:new.trt_procedure, 1);
   END IF;

 ELSIF DELETING THEN
   UPDATE B SET trt_del_count = trt_del_count+1
   WHERE B.trt_procedure = :old.trt_procedure;
   IF SQL%NOTFOUND THEN
   INSERT INTO B (trt_procedure, trt_del_count)
   VALUES (:old.trt_procedure, 1);
   END IF;
 END IF;
END trt_stats_trg;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, with a few fixes.

The tables:

```
create table a(
  TRT_ID  NUMBER(3) NOT NULL ,
  PAT_NBR          NUMBER(4),
  PHYS_ID          NUMBER(3),
  TRT_PROCEDURE    VARCHAR2(5),
  TRT_DATE         DATE
);
create table b(
  TRT_PROCEDURE VARCHAR2(5) NOT NULL,
  TRT_INS_COUNT          NUMBER(3),
  TRT_DEL_COUNT          NUMBER(3),
  TRT_UPD_COUNT          NUMBER(3)
);
```

And the trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trt_stats_trg
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON A FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF INSERTING THEN
    UPDATE B SET trt_ins_count = nvl(trt_ins_count,0)+1
      WHERE B.trt_procedure = :new.trt_procedure;
    IF SQL%NOTFOUND THEN
      INSERT INTO B (trt_procedure, trt_ins_count)
      VALUES (:new.trt_procedure, 1);
    END IF;

 ELSIF UPDATING('TRT_PROCEDURE') THEN
   if nvl(:old.trt_procedure, 'X') <> nvl(:new.trt_procedure, 'X') then
     UPDATE B SET trt_upd_count = nvl(trt_upd_count,0)+1
       WHERE B.trt_procedure = :old.trt_procedure;
     IF SQL%NOTFOUND THEN
       INSERT INTO B (trt_procedure, trt_upd_count)
       VALUES (:old.trt_procedure, 1);
     END IF;
     UPDATE B SET trt_upd_count = nvl(trt_upd_count,0)+1
       WHERE B.trt_procedure = :new.trt_procedure;
     IF SQL%NOTFOUND THEN
       INSERT INTO B (trt_procedure, trt_upd_count)
       VALUES (:new.trt_procedure, 1);
     END IF;
   end if;
 ELSIF DELETING THEN
   UPDATE B SET trt_del_count = nvl(trt_del_count, 0)+1
   WHERE B.trt_procedure = :old.trt_procedure;
   IF SQL%NOTFOUND THEN
     INSERT INTO B (trt_procedure, trt_del_count)
     VALUES (:old.trt_procedure, 1);
   END IF;
 END IF;
END trt_stats_trg;
/
```

Key points:

- You can use `UPDATING('COLUMN_NAME')` to detect when the SQL affects a specific column.
- When `UPDATING`, you may wish to check for non-changing updates, where a column with value "ABC" is being updated to "ABC". This often happens in frameworks that simply include all columns in an update even when they are not really changing. Detect this with something similar to `if nvl(:old.trt_procedure, 'X') <> nvl(:new.trt_procedure, 'X') then`.
- Table `B` does not have default values for the counts, so when the original trigger tried to update table `B`, it succeeded...in updating `NULL` to `NULL`, as that's what happens when you add 1 to `NULL`. This can be addressed by either assigning a default value of `0` to the columns in the table or by using `NVL(trt_upd_count,0) + 1` instead of `trt_upd_count + 1`.
- Finally, watch out for usages of `:new` and `:old`. It looks like they are correct in this trigger, but it will depend on your business case.

Answer (score 0):

In the `IF INSERTING` section of your trigger you have

```
UPDATE B
  SET trt_ins_count = trt_ins_count+1
  WHERE :old.trt_procedure = :new.trt_procedure;
```

When inserting a new row all values in the `:OLD` pseudorow are NULL and thus your UPDATE will never update anything. I think you meant

```
UPDATE B
  SET trt_ins_count = trt_ins_count+1
  WHERE B.trt_procedure = :new.trt_procedure;
```

Give that a try and see if that helps solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, the `IF UPDATING` section is the problem.

Comment: I edit it as this but it doesn't count updated TRT_PROCEDURE correctly.

Comment: `IF UPDATING THEN
            UPDATE B SET trt_upd_count = trt_upd_count+1
            WHERE B.trt_procedure = :old.trt_procedure;
             IF SQL%NOTFOUND THEN
             INSERT INTO B (trt_procedure, trt_upd_count)
             VALUES (:old.trt_procedure, 1);
             END IF;
             UPDATE B SET trt_upd_count = trt_upd_count+1
             WHERE B.trt_procedure = :new.trt_procedure;
             IF SQL%NOTFOUND THEN
             INSERT INTO B (trt_procedure, trt_upd_count)
             VALUES (:new.trt_procedure, 1);
             END IF;   END IF;`

Comment: Your update procedure double counts whenever a column in table A other than trt_procedure is updated but trt_procedure does not is updated. You increment the for :old.trt_procedure and for :new_trt_procedure even when they are the same.

Comment: I revised the trigger as suggested.Thanks for the hints, unfortunately the problem still persists. Revised code as above.